# How to get NPC to Find and Follow Path to other NPC?

Tags: path-finding, skyrim-modding

## Problem:

I am using **Skyrim Creation Kit** to create a very simple mod. I want the mod to make one NPC follow another NPC. My first problem is that I am not really 100% sure where to start. The second problem is which functions I should use. I have been reading the documentation at [www.creationkit.com](http://creationkit.com/). In other words:

```
LOOP: { 
  // move Bob to Mike's current position with speed of 0.5
  (npc_Bob.moveToPosition( npc_Mike.getPos(), 0.5 )
} // end loop
```

---

## My Attempt:

I tried making a quest but to no avail. So then I made 2 custom actors (`member` and `leader`) and I put this script in `member`:

```
Scriptname NpcFollowNpc extends ObjectReference
//***put a loop once you get this part working
// moves member to leader with speed of 0.5
member.PathToReference(leader, 0.5)
```

but it didn't compile. I don't really know if this is the right way to implement what I want. I know how to code and make algorithms and a bunch of that computer science stuff, but I don't know how to move the actor `member` to the location of actor `leader` in Skyrim and loop it while the actor `leader` is alive.

Any ideas how I could go about doing this? thanks for any help/feedback!

Answer (score 1):

[As stated in this forum,](https://steamcommunity.com/app/25000/discussions/0/630800443056921259/) you will need to Spawn a path point, attach it to an NPC. Then press U with the pathpoint selected to open the parameters. In the first text field, the one called Type, replace "Stand" with whatever (has to be written with a capital letter)

Comment: That's an interesting method. I actually used a different approach - I will post on here later, but basically I assigned a custom package (that used the Follow Package Template) to an actor. More info [here.](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Follow_(Procedure))

Comment: @Ibrahim to be honest, I know little on Skyrim modding. I just had found the forum and put some of it's knowledge and my own into the answer. :)

Comment: I appreciate your input! I did not think of the way you suggested so I learned something new.